# Complex Regex to search for a phrase and then a number within a limited scope

Tags: regex

I'm trying to understand why the following dosen't work.

`\b(?:CNC\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,6}[\d])\b`

Each section will work on there own, I can find the key phrase or I can find the number and the match within 6 words works in other regex within the same system.

I've been using RegexBuddy to build the code and checking on various website before coming here.

I just don't understand why this dosen't work.  I am limited to only python based regex in the environment this is for.

I would love an answer that would fix it but would really love to understand where I'm going wrong

Regards

Comment: what are you trying to match..can you show us some valid sample inputs.

Comment: Here is a live example using your regex http://regexr.com?359qd and it matches some text groups in the paragraph. Hover over each section of regex to get the explanation. What exactly are you trying to match?

Comment: N an iPad at the moment so unable to view the example, but will be on a real computer later tonight.

Comment: I am trying to capture a match like _the number of CNC machines equalled 5_

Comment: @Anirudh Here some additional samples of what I want to match "CNC operators numbering 12" and the reverse like "There are 12 qualified CNC operators on site"  Basically any number within a 6 word count of the key phrase.

Comment: @lurii.K so the code should work.  It looks like the error must be within RegexBuddy then as it never matches that regex to any sample text.

Comment: "Basically any number within a 6 word count of the key phrase." - Then, you may use `(\d+)\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,5}CNC\b|\bCNC\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,5}(\d+)` and grab Group 1 or Group 2 values. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TbLZun/1).

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
(\d+)\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,5}CNC\b|\bCNC\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,5}(\d+)
```

The [regex demo is available here](https://regex101.com/r/TbLZun/1). Your expected values are in Group 1 and Group 2.

**Details**

- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits
- `\W+` - 1+ non-word chars
- `(?:\w+\W+){0,5}` - 0 to 5 repetitions of 1+ word chars and 1+ non-word chars
- `CNC\b` - a whole word `CNC`
- `|` - or
- `\bCNC` - a whole word CNC
- `\W+` - 1+ non-word chars
- `(?:\w+\W+){0,5}` - 0 to 5 repetitions of 1+ word chars and 1+ non-word chars
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 2: one or more digits

In [Python](https://ideone.com/t2eDtD):

```
import re
s = '''the number of CNC machines equalled 5 I want to match "CNC operators numbering 12" and the reverse like "There are 12 qualified CNC operators on site'''
rx = r'(\d+)\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,5}CNC\b|\bCNC\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,5}(\d+)'
print(["{}{}".format(x,y) for x,y in re.findall(rx, s)])
# => ['5', '12', '12']
```